# Remove class from body when modal is closed with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I have multiple modals on my page that open when click on the respective button.
When a modal is open it adds the class `.has-modal-open` to the body to prevent the page from scrolling.
The problem is when I close the modal that class doesn't get removed from the body tag. I tried `body.classList.remove('has-modal-open');` but for some reason it just doesn't work.
I'm looking for a vanilla javascript solution.

Thank you.

```js
  const modal = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
  const modalOpenButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-open-modal]');
  const modalCloseButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-close-modal]');
  const body = document.querySelector('body');
  
  for (let i = 0; i < modalOpenButtons.length; i++) {
    const modalOpenButton = modalOpenButtons[i];
    modalOpenButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
      body.classList.add('has-modal-open');
      const modalDataAttribute = e.target.getAttribute('data-open-modal');
      document.querySelector('.modal[data-open-modal=\''.concat(modalDataAttribute, '\']')).classList.add('modal--is-open');
    });
  }
  
  for (let i = 0; i < modalCloseButtons.length; i++) {
    body.classList.remove('has-modal-open');
    const modalCloseButton = modalCloseButtons[i];
    modalCloseButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
      e.target.closest('.modal').classList.remove('modal--is-open');
    });
  }
  
  for (let i = 0; i < modal.length; i++) {
    const modals = modal[i];
    document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
      if (e.keyCode === 27) {
        modals.classList.remove('modal--is-open')
      }
    })
    modals.addEventListener('click', e => {
      e.target.classList.remove('modal--is-open')
    })
  }
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: calc(100% - 48px);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  z-index: 90;
}

.modal__header {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 60px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.modal__body {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - 48px);
  max-width: 900px;
  max-height: calc(100% - 48px);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-height: 700px;
  background: white;
}

.modal__content {
  padding: 0 40px 40px;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

.modal--is-open {
  display: flex;
}

.has-modal-open {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}


.modal__close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;
  right: 12px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" data-open-modal="open-modal-1">Open modal</button>

<div class="modal" data-open-modal="open-modal-1">
  <div class="modal__body">
    <div class="modal__header">
      <button class="modal__close" data-close-modal>X</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal__content">
      My modal
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has 2 problems:

- `body.classList.remove('has-modal-open');` should be called inside the eventListener for the close button, but you call it before.
- `modalOpenButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-open-modal]');` selects not only the buttons, but also your modals with the attribute `data-open-modal`. When you click the close button, the modal gets clicked as well, and so in your case calls the eventListener attached to `modalOpenButtons`. You should put only the buttons in `modalOpenButtons`, for example like this:

`const modalOpenButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-open-modal]');`

I made a snippet here below, where you can see that the class gets added/removed correctly

```js
const modal = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
  const modalOpenButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-open-modal]');
  const modalCloseButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-close-modal]');
  const body = document.querySelector('body');
  
  for (let i = 0; i < modalOpenButtons.length; i++) {
    const modalOpenButton = modalOpenButtons[i];
    modalOpenButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
      body.classList.add('has-modal-open');
      const modalDataAttribute = e.target.getAttribute('data-open-modal');
      //document.querySelector(`.modal[data-open-modal="${modalDataAttribute}"]`).classList.add('modal--is-open');
      document.querySelector('.modal[data-open-modal=\''.concat(modalDataAttribute, '\']')).classList.add('modal--is-open');
    });
  }
  
  for (let i = 0; i < modalCloseButtons.length; i++) {
    const modalCloseButton = modalCloseButtons[i];
    modalCloseButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
      body.classList.remove('has-modal-open');
      e.target.closest('.modal').classList.remove('modal--is-open');
    });
  }
  
  for (let i = 0; i < modal.length; i++) {
    const modals = modal[i];
    document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
      if (e.keyCode === 27) {
        modals.classList.remove('modal--is-open')
      }
    })
    modals.addEventListener('click', e => {
      e.target.classList.remove('modal--is-open')
    })
  }
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: calc(100% - 48px);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  z-index: 90;
}

.modal__header {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 60px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.modal__body {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100% - 48px);
  max-width: 900px;
  max-height: calc(100% - 48px);
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 4px;
  max-height: 700px;
  background: white;
}

.modal__content {
  padding: 0 40px 40px;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

.modal--is-open {
  display: flex;
}

.has-modal-open {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}


.modal__close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 32px;
  right: 12px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 56px;
  height: 56px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" data-open-modal="open-modal-1">Open modal</button>

<div class="modal" data-open-modal="open-modal-1">
  <div class="modal__body">
    <div class="modal__header">
      <button class="modal__close" data-close-modal>X</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal__content">
      My modal
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

your error simply says that

```
"message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')",
```

which means in your code `body` is representing `null`
there can be several reasons why this happened
one might be that you haven't accessed it in proper way